# Displaying a graphic layer derived from an ArcGIS Server geoprocessing task on a WebApp map

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, web-mapping

I know this should be basic, but I am trying to get an output from a ArcGIS Server geoprocessing task of data type "GPFeatureRecordSetLayer" to be added into a map on a WebApp. here is the code (the " in the http is to break the link):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> @import "h"ttp://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.3/js/dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
@import "h"ttp://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.3/js/esri/css/esri.css";
@import "h"ttp://141.209.164.112:6080/arcgis/rest/static/jsapi.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.3"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

dojo.require("esri.tasks.gp");
dojo.require("esri.map");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");


function init(){
    var map= new esri.Map("maper");
    var gpAdd2 = new esri.tasks.Geoprocessor(/*name of server*/);
    gpAdd2.execute(/*prams*/);
    dojo.connect(gpAdd2,"onExecuteComplete",onTaskSuccess);
    function onTaskSuccess(results,messages){
        require(["esri/graphic","esri/graphicsUtils"], 
        function(Graphic,graphicsUtils){
            var features = results[0].value.features;
            for (var f=0;f < features.length; f++){
                console.log(f);
                var feature = features[f];
                map.graphic.add(feature);
                console.log(feature);
            }
            map.setExtent(graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(map.graphics.graphics), true);
        });
    }
}
dojo.addOnLoad(init);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="maper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

as far as I can tell it gets the results fine but for whatever reason the map.graphic.add(feature); line crashes the code.

the onTaskSuccess function is modeled after a tutorial found here:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/gp_viewshed.html